Compare Listbox Column Value to TextBox Value
I have a multicolumn Listbox with three columns and one row. I also have a TextBox. What I want to do is to compare the value in the TextBox to the last column value in the Listbox.
I have the following code but it does not work properly.
     Dim i as Integer
     For i = 0 To Me.Listbox1.ListCount -1   
       If Me.Listbox1.List(i, 2) < Me.Textbox1.Value Then 
         MsgBox "Insufficient Fund"       
       Else
         MsgBox "Sufficient Fund"
       End If 
     Next i

I have tried all I could to get this to work but to no avail. I wonder what I am doing wrong. Will be grateful if you guys can help and correct me.
Thanks

Currently you are issuing a MsgBox for every row in the listbox. Probably not what you want.

I arranged your code to make more sense... Did you try it as it became?  Does the code raise any error or simple it runs but nothing happens? Where the code you show exists? In an event code (a click event of a button, change event of the text box etc.)?

@FunThomas I have one row only with 3 columns

@FaneDuru can you show me your rearranged code. Can't see it

I meant, the code as it looks now in your code. And I also asked about some other aspects... Now I am driving, anyhow.

I don't get the idea of having only one row in a listbox. Anyhow, I just saw that you are using the "Less Than" operator. Note that content of a listbox and a textbox is always a string, therefore 100 < 90. If you want to compare numbers, you need to convert both values to numbers, eg by using Val or CDbl or CLng

@FunThomas well what I mean by one row is that I don't have the column headers loaded into my Listbox. Also I have tried to use Val to convert them into numbers but it did not work. I keep on getting the message after the Else statement.
